# C# HttpClient 504 Gateway Timeout when not using Fiddler proxy

Tags: c#, http, fiddler

I have this simple code to instantiate an HttpClient object, and send a few webrequests, but am running into a few problems that I will explain shortly:

```
var client = WebHelper.CreateGzipHttpClient(new WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 8888));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Sec-Fetch-Mode", "navigate");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Sec-Fetch-Site", "none");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Sec-Fetch-User", "?1");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");

await client.GetAsync("https://www.example.com");
await client.GetAsync("https://www.bestbuy.com");
await client.GetAsync("https://www.costco.com");
```

If I remove the request to example.com, the subsequent requests fail (504 Gateway Timeout on bestbuy.com).  Doesn't make any sense to me, so was wondering if someone on SO could enlighten me as to why that is.

Furthermore, if I remove the WebProxy from the HttpClient, only the request to example.com will succeed, and the other 2 will fail.

What is going on and how can I fix it?

```
public static HttpClient CreateGzipHttpClient(WebProxy proxy = null)
{
    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate,
        Proxy = proxy
    };

    return new HttpClient(handler);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by removing the Fiddler related SSL certificates within Internet Explorer's Internet Options.  These weren't being removed even after an uninstall.